# Retrieve python dictionary value by using numpy array as a key in time efficient way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I'm using python 3.6 .I have a numpy array let's say a.It's in this format

```
array(['0', '1', '2', ..., '3304686', '3304687', '3304688'],
      dtype='<U7')
```

I have another dictionary b={1: '012', 2: '023', 3: '045',.....3304688:'01288'}

I want to retrieve each value of b and store it in another numpy array by providing the value of a as a key to b. I was planning to try in this way

```
    z_array = np.array([])  

    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        z=b[i]        
        z_array=np.append(z_array,z)
```

But looking the shape of a,I'm feeling that it will be very much time consuming.
Can you please suggest me some alternate approach which will be time efficient?

Comment: do *not* use `z_array=np.append(` in a loop. That gives you quadratic time. Instead, initailize `z_array = np.zeros_like(a)` Then loop and assign to `z_array[i] = b[i]`

Comment: Why are you working with array of strings anway? You are essentially giving up the speed/space-benefits of numpy arrays. Your strings look like they represent numbers, why not numbers?

Comment: Are the array values strings? If so, why aren't the keys of dict strings too? Also, shouldn't that be `for i in a:`? And what if the keys are not available?

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, I will try that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.Instead of np.append,I used your approach & it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.frompyfunc`, note that this will create an object array.

```
b = {str(i): i**3 for i in range(10**7)}
a = [str(i) for i in range(10**7)]
c = np.frompyfunc(b.__getitem__, 1, 1)(a)
```

or

```
c = np.frompyfunc(b.get, 1, 1)(a)
```

to indicate missing keys by `None`.

In the example with 10,000,000 items and as many lookups takes just a second or two. (Creating `a` and `b` takes longer)

Comment: Thanks @Paul Panzer, I will try this